# How to highlight a language certificate in a resume/CV?

Tags: resume

When I learned Russian, I did an official examination and got a certificate assessing my language level. As this certificate is quite hard to get (it is the equivalent of a C1 CEFR level), I would like to highlight it. How can I do that on my resume? Should I make a comment about it in the language skill section or put it in education?

**Disclaimer**: my question is not about [how to indicate languages on a resume](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/10006/how-should-i-indicate-language-proficiency-on-my-resume), but specifically about highlighting a language certificate.

Comment: PS: in case it is useful information: the certificate is called TORFL (test of Russian as a foreign language) or ТРКИ (Тест по русскому языку как иностранному) in Russian. I passed the level 3 (highest is 4).

Comment: I'd treat it as any other professional qualification, but if you do put it on your resume then be prepared for the first interview question to be in that language.

Comment: If important for job - write it in summary at the very top. Not to be considered as a joke - write a section in your resume in Russian (e.g. using picture, not text so that it would be displayed properly even if recruiter does not have fonts installed), duplicating it in English.

Comment: It is not that important for the job, but I want to highlight this as a proof of my learning ability

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how relevant Russian is to the job being sought, it could go two places:

1) If important, put it near the top with info such as nationality, marital status and so on

2) If it's just a side note - and you have more certifications - perhaps list them all in a separate section

Comment: Good point, a specific "other certifications" is an option. However I don't have others to show than that and my degree (I'm a young graduate)

Answer (score 1):

I would make a section Language like this after education section:

```
+----------+-----+
|Language  |Level|
+----------+-----+
|English   |C1   |
+----------+-----+
|Russian   |C1   |
+----------+-----+
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have other certifications, I'd put it with the other certifications along with a date received.

If languages are important for the jobs you're applying, I'd put them as a separate category along with the cert, again with the date you had received the cert.

And if you really want to highlight it and have a profile section and a cover letter, I'd mention the cert in both the profile and cover letter.